# Tomcat9 application status is false and throwing 404 when trying to access the server path

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat9

I am starting the tomcat server from eclipse and I have manually copied .war file into tomcat C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps folder.

But when I check the running status of app from tomcat application manager, I see running status of that application - False: http://localhost:8081/manager/html

Here is the log I get while starting the server from eclipse :

```
Jun 15, 2020 2:15:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\nn.war]
Jun 15, 2020 2:15:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\nn.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45009)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45012)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@36061cf3]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4936)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.__newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45009)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45012)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:233)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \usr\share\java\jersey-server.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1763)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1225)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:727)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:348)
    ... 56 more

Jun 15, 2020 2:15:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\nn.war] has finished in [39] ms
Jun 15, 2020 2:15:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
Jun 15, 2020 2:15:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

Environment : Java 11

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the war file was generated using ant build process and according to that there was a dependency on lib files which tomcat was expecting at certain location. Creating a folder in that location fixed the issue.

here is the snippet of build file:

```
 <target name="war" depends="clean,compile">
        <war destfile="dist/nn.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
            <!--
            <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
            -->
            <classes dir="build/classes"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Class-Path"  value="\
/usr/share/java/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar \
/usr/share/java/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar \
/usr/share/java/jersey-media-jaxb.jar \

"/> 
            </manifest>
        </war>
```